# Problem connecting Access navigation form to other forms and reports

Tags: ms-access

I am working on an Access DB. I have table with Course information connected to table with grades.
I created a query to display all Courses grades.
Then based on this query, I created a form with a combo box to filter the grades of only one Course. In this form, I added a button to open a report for this Course grades, this report contains another button to print this report as PDF.
It worked perfectly till I added it to a navigation form.
I changed the filter code to work and it is working. However, the button to open the report is not.

In the navigation Form, the following is the the on_Click code I used for the button:

```
Private Sub Command47_Click()
   Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strReportName As String
    
    'Get the value of the combo box
    strFilter = "[CourseCode] = " & Me.Combo25.Value
    
    'Set the name of the report to open
    strReportName = "RCourse"
    
    'Open the report with the filter applied
    DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, , strFilter
```

In the report, I used this code for the On_Open event:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
 Dim strFilter As String
    
    'Check if the Combo box in the form is not empty
    If Not IsNull(Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![Combo25]) Then
        'Get the selected value from the combo box
        strFilter = "'" & Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![Combo25] & "'"
        
        'Apply the filter to the report's Record Source query
        Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM [QCourse] WHERE [CourseCode]='" & strFilter & "'"
    End If
```

When I run the navigation form, I set Couse Code then click on the button to open the report but I get this error message:

Run time Error 3075
SYntax error (missing operator) in query expression
'[CourseCode]="Math101"'

Can you tell me what is wrong here and how to correct it to work

Thank you in advance

Comment: CourseCode is a text field so need apostrophe delimiters: `"[CourseCode]='" & Me.Combo25 & "'"`. Why would you need to set report RecordSource property? The report is already opened with filter criteria from form code. Did you remove code from the report event? If so, posting it was not necessary. Suggest you give controls more meaningful names.

Comment: Hmm, I read your post again and see that the error shows quote mark delimiters in the compiled criteria, however, your code does not show using delimiters so how do those quote marks get in there (which should work)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approaches they all work.  In the code you show Math101 ends up delimited twice.  once when you get StringFilter  (StringFilter= 'Math101') then again when you set the recordsource ( [CourseCode] = ''Math101'').  You are filtering the report to Math101 then setting the recordsource to only include Math101 which is redundant.

Comment: Thank you so much, I rewrote the code again taking your comments in to consideration and it works